# SQL query most recent scan date

Tags: sql

I am using the following query to pull the most recent scan dates for 5 different scan names, however the data being returned is just showing the most recent date for 1 of the scan names.

The query is just returning the most recent scan date overall, which is 4/18/12 for the scan name 'fisma-mgmt'. The other 4 scan dates which were on 4/17/12 are not displaying. Can anyone see what would be causing this result?

```
SELECT 
ScanName,
ScanDate,
pspplMSSeverity,
PatchMissing

FROM
(
SELECT
ScanName,
ScanDate,
pspplMSSeverity,
PatchMissing,

DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ScanDate DESC) AS Rnk

FROM qryReportsPatchDeploymentPctbyPatch

where (ScanName like '%fisma-front%'
OR ScanName like '%fisma-back%'
OR ScanName like '%fisma-app%'
OR ScanName like '%fisma-meps%'
OR ScanName like '%fisma-mgmt%')


)t
WHERE rnk=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, in the windows function, you need a partition clause:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ScanName ORDER BY ScanDate DESC) AS Rnk
```

As written, the query only returns the most recent scan overall, rather than the most recent scan for each name.

Comment: @Bharata . . . I suspect that someone spam upvoted my answers to do that.  I am expecting an adjustment in the next day or two, removing those upvotes.  As a consequence, there is probably no single person who put me over 1 million (while I was sleeping, by the way).